# Can I define a text property as rich text?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

VS 2013, VB, EF6

I am creating an object that will keep user input in one of its properties.  I would like that user input to be stored as rich text.  What's involved to make that stored text be rich text format?  So,

```
Public Property Text as <what?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would post what was my answer for others who might ask the question the same way I did.  I begin by stating that my question was poorly formed because I didn't understand I'm not really storing RTF, I'm storing WYSIWYG text with html tags. But I think the question as phrased is useful because that's how many people think until they are taught by others.

Ultimately this process opens a serious XSS vector, but first we have to at least collect the WYSIWYG text.

**First step:** using a script-based editor capture the text with html tags.  I used [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/about/license) which is easy to download on NuGet.  It comes in 3 flavors: basic, standard and full.  Another popular one seems to be [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php) also available through NuGet.

CKEditor must be 'wired in' to replace the existing input element. I replaced @html.editorfor with a < textarea > directly as follows. Model.UserPost.Body is the property into which I want to place the WYSIWYG text.  The Raw helper is required so the output is NOT encoded allowing us to see our WYSIWYG text.

```
<textarea name="model.UserPost.Body" id="model_UserPost_Body" class="form-control text-box multi-line">
  @Html.Raw(Model.UserPost.Body)
</textarea>
```

CKEditor is 'wired in' using a script element to replace the < textarea > element.

```
@Section Scripts
  <script src="~/scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('model.UserPost.Body');
  </script>
End Section
```

The script above can be added to all pages via _layout.vbhtml, or just the target page via a @Section Scripts section as shown above, which is often recommended and what I did, but that may also require adding to the standard _Layout the following in the < head > section such as follows.

```
@RenderSection("Styles", False)
```

In the controller POST method for the view the following code is needed to capture the WYSIWYG text otherwise the default filter will raise an exception when it detects anything that looks like an html tag.

```
Dim rawBody = Request.Unvalidated.Form("model.UserPost.Body")
userPost.Body = rawBody
```

There are some possible gotcha's; The 'body' property has to be removed from the Include:= list of the < Bind > element in the method paramter list if < Bind > is being used.  Also, although not directly related to this solution, you can't have a Data Annotation like < Required() > on this property in the model because background checking won't be able to confirm that condition so the ModelState.IsValid flag won't ever go true.

**Second step**: before saving the input it **MUST** be checked for XSS.  Microsoft has a [nice video explaining basic XSS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/gg675034.aspx) that I recommend viewing; it's only 11 minutes.

Mikesdotnetting has a nice explaination for dealing with XSS and shows a whitelisting algorithm toward the bottom of [this page](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/222/request-validation-in-asp-net-web-pages).  The following code is based on his work.

To create a white listing approach, the HTML Agility Pack is useful to catalogue the HTML nodes for review.  This is easily loaded from Nu Get as well.  This is the code I used in the POST method to invoke the white list methods (Yes, it could be more compact, but this is easier to read for us novices):

```
Dim tempDoc = New HtmlDocument()
tempDoc.LoadHtml(rawBody)
RemoveNodes(tempDoc.DocumentNode, allowedTags)
userPost.Body = tempDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
```

The allowed tags are what you will allow, which means everything else is rejected, hence whitelisting.  This is just a sample list:

```
Dim allowedTags As New List(Of String)() From {"p", "em", "s", "ol", "ul", "li", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "strong"}
```

These are the methods based on Mikesdotnetting page:

```
Private Sub RemoveNodes(ByVal node As HtmlNode, allowedTags As List(Of String))
  If (node.NodeType = HtmlNodeType.Element) Then
    If Not allowedTags.Contains(node.Name) Then
      node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node)
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If

  If (node.HasChildNodes) Then
    RemoveChildren(node, allowedTags)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveChildren(ByVal parent As HtmlNode, allowedTags As List(Of String))
  For i = parent.ChildNodes.Count() - 1 To 0 Step -1
    RemoveNodes(parent.ChildNodes(i), allowedTags)
  Next
End Sub
```

So basically, (1) CKEditor captures user input with html tags that looks nice, (2) the **raw input** is specially requested in the Controller POST method and then (3) cleaned using a white list.  After that it can be output directly to the page using @Html.Raw() because it can be trusted.

That's it.  I've not really posted solutions like this before, so if I've missed something let me know and I'll correct or add it.

Comment: Re the title, perhaps a better title is needed for other newbies like me to find this, I'm just not sure what that should be.

Answer (score -1):

Rich Text is stored in the Rich Text Format.

The Rich Text Format specifications can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725

It is just an ordinary string. You can extract the string from a RichTextBox using the `SaveFile` function:

```
Private Function GetRTF(ByRef Box As RichTextBox) As String
    Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream
        Box.SaveFile(ms, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
        Return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray)
    End Using
End Function
```

You can load text in the Rich Text Format into a RichTextBox using the `LoadFile` method of the RichTextBox. The text needs to be in the correct format:

```
Dim rtf As String = "{\rtf1 {\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;}Guten Tag!\line{\i Dies} ist ein\line formatierter {\b Text}.\line Das {\cf1 Ende}.}"
Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtf))
    RichTextBox1.LoadFile(ms, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
End Using
```

Ordinary controls usually will not interpret this format in their text property.

Comment: This is not technically correct, wrong encoding.  Just don't bother, simply use the Rtf property.

Comment: Is ASCII the correct encoding? Seems so from what I've found now. I did not notice the RTF property, that would have saved me some time ;-)